# Mac OSX Docker Desktop alpine container cannot communicate with particular host

Tags: macos, docker

I experience strange behaviour on `Mac OSX Docker Desktop` when I start a container and try to access a service say at http://repository.test.example.com/repository.

So I start alpine `docker run -it alpine` and run command `curl http://repository.test.example.com/repository` However same service running on another environment 
`http://repository.stage.example.com/repository` works.

Verified:

1. Remote service is running. Using curl on Mac shell works
2. Started a Ubuntu VM install docker and checked it works on there too
3. Colleague  did not have the same issue

So the issue seems to be related to when container started in Mac OSX directly particularly my Mac.

**Commands**

```sh
docker run -it alpine
apk add curl
curl http://repository.test.example.com/repository
# Does not receive content just hangs until timeout
```

**Solution**

Realised it has to be something to do with my Docker Desktop. I re-installed but no luck. However I saw my settings for Docker desktop doesn't change. So I needed to remove user settings for Docker Desktop in order to fix it.

Identified any preference files in following folders

- ls -l /Users/username/Library/ApplicationSupport | grep -i docker (removing this had no -impact)
- ls -l /Users/username/Library/Preferences | grep -i docker  (removing this had no impact)
- ls -l /Users/username/Library/Containers/ | grep -i docker
- ls -l /Users/username/Library/Group\ Containers/ | grep -i docker

and remove any files and folder. This cleared all the user specific settings and Docker Desktop started fresh. Then the issue is solved as well.

If you need to remove any user settings for application, check and remove relevant files and folders from above directories.

Another useful post [Where do OSX applications typically store user configuration data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410013/where-do-osx-applications-typically-store-user-configuration-data/36725188#36725188)

Comment: I'm not really following what your question is.  Can you provide a [mcve] for this setup, including any relevant application code, Dockerfiles, `docker run` commands, _etc._?  When it doesn't work, what specific error do you get?

Comment: command used here was, starting docker container with docker run -it alpine and then run command curl http://repository.test.example.com/repository for this curl command traffic does not go outside the container. I could see SYN packed send but not response receive. Howerver same performed for the url http://repository.stage.example.com/repository it worked. Initially thought it was network issue and worked with network team but no luck. Important item here is that there might have been some user config caused the issue. In oder to solve the issue had to cleanup the user preferences.